# How to sum one column value by a different range in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
range      number  Value
3600-3700  1301    5
3700-3800  1301    6
3600-3700  1302    10
3700-3800  1302    12
3800-3900  1301    3
3800-3900  1302    4
3900-4000  1301    5
3900-4000  1302    6
```

This is my input, I want my output to be,

```
range      number  Value
3600-3800  1301    11
3600-3800  1302    22
3800-4000  1301    8
3800-4000  1302    10
```

I want to sum the value column with a new range value. can anyone help me? I am using pandas

Comment: `df.groupby("number")["Value"].sum()` will give you what you want aside from the range column. To get the range string the way you want you'll maybe need to split and do a `min`/`max` on a `groupby`. Not sure if a more elegant way

Comment: I did the df.groupby("number")["Value"].sum() but as you mentioned, it gives me the sum of all ranges. For the range col, my goal is to sum by a different interval every 200s instead of 100. So the next range will be 3800-4000. So, min/max will not work. Instead of groupby min/max can I specify a value/range?

Comment: Do guarantee that the ranges of one number are continuous? like (3600-3700)(3700-3800) and are there only two identical ranges for each number? - The answer to these questions will give the rules to get what you want.

Comment: Yes, they are continuous. And all the number has same continuous ranges. So, both 1301 and 1302 have (3600-3700),(3700-3800)....(25100-25200).

Comment: how are the output ranges defined.  if you group by number and the min and max it produces a hierarchy.  my hierarchy looks different from yours.

Comment: Your desired output does not agree with your asking `I want to sum the value column with a new range` and no one can understand the logic you want, even when the proposed answers met your proposed output, you change both input data and the proposed output - This is not logic and clear target.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's add `min` and `max` value of the column `range` so that we can make use of it more conveniently.

```
df['min_range'] = df['range'].str.split("-").apply(lambda x: min(x))
df['max_range'] = df['range'].str.split("-").apply(lambda x: max(x))

df
    range       number  value   min_range   max_range
0   3600-3700   1301    5   3600    3700
1   3700-3800   1301    6   3700    3800
2   3600-3700   1302    10  3600    3700
3   3700-3800   1302    12  3700    3800
```

Then, we should have a `groupby` with different aggregate functions for different columns and we do it as follows:

```
df_final = df.groupby('number').agg({
            'min_range': 'min', 
            'max_range': 'max',
            'value': 'sum'
            })
df_final
    min_range   max_range   value
number          
1301    3600    3800    11
1302    3600    3800    22
```

If you want to combine `min_range` and `max_range` to have just one column as `range`, you can do the following:

```
df_final['range'] = df_final['min_range'].astype(str) + "-" + df_final['max_range'].astype(str)
df_final.drop(columns=['min_range', 'max_range'], inplace=True)
df_final

        value   range
number      
1301    11  3600-3800
1302    22  3600-3800
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am trying to get the sum of value in a different interval, from 100 to 200. The min,  max is not working for me as I want the next set of data aggregated this way,        3800-4000, 4000-4200 for all numbers 1301,1302 and so on. all the number has same continuous ranges. So, both 1301 and 1302 have (3600-3700),(3700-3800)....(25100-25200)..

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Could you please update your question with examples of what you want so that I can help you better?

Answer (score 0):

```
  df=pd.read_csv('ranges.csv',dtype= {'range':'string','number':'string','value':np.int32})
  print(df.columns)
  #df['min'],df['max'],*rest=df['range'].str.split('-')

  key=0
  for x,y in df['range'].str.split('-'):
       df.loc[key,'min']=x
       df.loc[key,'max']=y
       key+=1

   print(df.groupby(['number','min','max'])['value'].sum())

 output:
 number  min   max 
 1301    3600  3700     5
         3700  3800     6
         3800  3900     3
         3900  4000     5
  1302   3600  3700    10
         3700  3800    12
         3800  3900     4
         3900  4000     6
```